# Office error `Office Software Protection Platform`?

Tags: microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010

I'm having this errors when trying to install office.

How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried running the installer as Administrator?

Comment: @Matt Yes, of course I have. Even if I don't, the installer will require that.

Answer (score 2):

Error 1923 can be a bit vague but was intended to mean that a previous version of office was found on the system and is creating a conflict.  Here's the official MS solution:

**To work around this issue, restart the computer after you remove the prerelease version of the 2007 Office programs.**

However you may not actually have a previous version as there are a few of other things that can cause this, such as aggressive anti-virus or, as Matt pointed out, insufficient privileges.