# Office 2016 setup fails with error 1923: Service 'Office Software Protection Platform' could not be installed

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office, microsoft-office-2016

I am trying to install Office 2016 Professional on Windows 7 SP1, and getting the following error:

> Error 1923. Service 'Office Software Protection Platform' (osppsvc) could not be installed. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to install system services.

This happens after an unsuccessful uninstall of the same Office version. The installer is running with administrative privileges.

So far I tried the following solutions, none helped:

1. Office 2016 removal tool from Microsoft (O15CTRRemove.exe). The tool warned me that "all" of the Office versions will be removed. I agreed (I have no other Office version), and in the end the tool notified me that the issues were resolved. It asked me to restart, which I did.
2. Office 2010 removal tool (MicrosoftEasyFix50450.exe). I did this because Googling error 1923 turned up this solution for Office 2010.
3. Granting Network Service access using:

   > icacls "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OfficeSoftwareProtectionPlatform" /grant "Network Service:F" /t

This is the exact problem described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/279445/office-error-office-software-protection-platform), but since this is a different Windows and Office versions, and since I wanted to detail the steps I took, I opened a new question. Hope that's OK.

Any thoughts?

Thanks

Comment: Could be an issue with the ISO / MSI you are installing from.  Try downloading the latest from Microsoft again.  Could also be an issue with the specific Windows user you are using... make a new Admin user and try while logged in as that one.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. The setup file is fine (it was already installed once), but I re-checked with a fresh copy anyway. Didn't work. Tried using another admin account, didn't help either, same error.

Comment: Here is a link to this issue on Microsoft support forums: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_install-mso_winother/office-2016-error-1920-service-office-software/17f770a7-d028-4f70-9757-df1ba1d1866e?tm=1494622071116